# Boolean method is not checking if statment

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, methods, boolean

I'm trying to write boolean method but it doesn't work

```
   public  boolean addPresent(Present present)
   {
      if(totWeight+present.getWeight()<=maxWeight)
      {
          presents.add(present);
          presents1.add(present);
          return true;

      }
          for(Present pres : presents1)
          {
          totWeight+=pres.getWeight();
          }return false;
   }
```

It's working if I write this method:

```
 public  void addPresent(Present present)
  {
       if(totWeight+present.getWeight()<=maxWeight)
      {
          presents.add(present);
          presents1.add(present);
         System.out.println("true");

      }else
      {             System.out.println("false");
      }
          for(Present pres : presents1)
          {
          totWeight+=pres.getWeight();
           }
 }
```

How should I make boolean method for it?

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also try using Boolean.

Comment: Don't try using Boolean.

Comment: it's adding all of present even if they weight more than maxWeight

Comment: i need to use boolean for it

Comment: avk was talking about Boolean which is different than boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return false before the for loop, or include the for loop inside the condition where you check that the weight will be less than maxWeight.
Or you could just add the weight of the present to totWeight, no need for for loop.

```
public  boolean addPresent(Present present){

    if(totWeight+present.getWeight()<=maxWeight){
        presents.add(present);
        presents1.add(present);
        totWeight += present.getWeight();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference I note is that it doesn't add anything to `totWeight` when you `return true`. I also think you wanted to reset the `total` with something like

```
public boolean addPresent(Present present) {
    boolean r = false;
    if (totWeight + present.getWeight() <= maxWeight) {
        presents.add(present);
        presents1.add(present);
        r = true;
    }
    totWeight = 0; // <-- reset total.
    for (Present pres : presents1) {
        totWeight += pres.getWeight();
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After cleaning up the formatting and comparing the two methods you described, I noticed one major logic fault.

In the first method, you do the following:

if true, return true and STOP running the rest of the method.  - 
if false, add all present weights and return false

In the second method, you do the following:

if true, return true and KEEP running the rest of the method. - 
if false, add all present weights and return false

If the first way is the way you want to do it, declare a boolean at the beginning of the method, and set it to true or false depending on result of test, and return that boolean instead.  That way you hold off on the actual return statement until you are done calculating.

```
public  boolean addPresent(Present present)
{
    boolean temp = false;
    if(totWeight+present.getWeight()<=maxWeight)
    {
        presents.add(present);
        presents1.add(present);
        temp = true;
    }
    for(Present pres : presents1)
    {
        totWeight+=pres.getWeight();
    }
    return temp;
```

}

Comment: As @Elliott Frisch said, you most likely want to reset the totWeight back to 0 before iterating through the loop, but we may be wrong.  If the 2nd method you listed does what you want, but just doesn't return the value, then go with above method.